# System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf-generation

Getting error when trying to generate PDF from HTML template. I have a different class library for generating PDF and I'm calling that from another controller.

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)'

Comment: Set Property `CopyLocal` as `true` for the DLL you have imported.

Comment: Check this thread, maybe it'll help https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

your csproj file to enforce copying NuGet assemblies to the built output:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running application in docker,then do an update to install libwkhtmltox dependencies for .netcore

```
# Install libwkhtmltox dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        zlib1g \
        fontconfig \
        libfreetype6 \
        libx11-6 \
        libxext6 \
        libxrender1 \
        libjpeg62-turbo
```

Answer (score 0):

Download package from https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/tree/master/v0.12.4

Add it to your project reference by custom Assembly reference & register in your startup project.
This is custom assembly load context which can load library from absolute path.

```js
internal class CustomAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    public IntPtr LoadUnmanagedLibrary(string absolutePath)
    {
        return LoadUnmanagedDll(absolutePath);
    }
    protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(String unmanagedDllName)
    {
        return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(unmanagedDllName);
    }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In Statup.cs add below code.
Call CustomAssemblyLoadContext before you create your converter:

> CustomAssemblyLoadContext context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
> context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(path);
>
> var converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());
> services.AddSingleton(converter);
> services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));